# Kotlin JNI - Unsatisfied link error when calling external function but not when loading library

Tags: kotlin, gradle, java-native-interface

C++ method signature:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_abc_de_fg_jni_ProxyControls_startProxy(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj);
```

Loading the library doesn't cause any errors:

```
package abc.de.fg.jni

class ProxyControls {
    init {
        System.load("/Users/***/***/lib***.dylib")
        println("loaded library")
    }

    external fun startProxy()
}
```

But running the startProxy method throws the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void abc.de.fg.jni.ProxyControls.startProxy()'
at abc.de.fg.jni.ProxyControls.startProxy(Native Method)
```

What have I done wrong?

More info:
Throwing an error on JNI_OnLoad crashes the app but throwing an error on startProxy() doesn't change the exception. So JNI_OnLoad is called but startProxy isn't called.

nm output: (filtered)

```
0000000000001e58 T _JNI_OnLoad
0000000000001ef4 T __Z51Java_abc_de_fg_jni_ProxyControls_startProxyP7JNIEnv_P8_jobject
```

Comment: Does `nm` confirm that that function exists in your dylib?

Comment: @Botje I added nm output to question

Comment: You forgot to declare your function as `extern "C" ` (or to include the header that does it for you)

Comment: @Botje yep, that was the problem. Thanks a lot!